# No storage in the disk error when there is plenty of storage left in it

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage, disk, storage, disk-management

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop. I'm trying to extract some file from a zip, during which I get low disk storage error indicating less than 1 GB is left and the extraction fails because of it. When I go to Disk Analyser app of Ubuntu, it shows 14 GB free storage available in my SSD then why am I getting this error?

Comment: You've given little detail for us to work on, but storage has more than one component for your *unstated* 20.04 system (you didn't specify if desktop, server, *flavor* etc).  If you run out of *inodes* on the file-system then you're out of disk space (ie. you can save larger files in place of existing files but cannot create more as file-system itself is filled).... You gave no clues as if you explore this, nor your system usage or what type of file you're *extracting* from (*running out of inodes occurs usually if you've loads of small files; you control this at format or use defaults*)

Comment: @guiverc I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 desktop. It's a zip file on my SSD from which I'm extracting some big sized video files. The disk usage app still shows around 14 GB free available but I cannot more files into the disk, it doesn't let me due to low size. The video files are less than 10 GB of size.

Comment: I've still got few details; you gave no clues as to *inodes*  (ie. `df -hi` will show diskfree detail with the `-i` telling it to include inodes free too), nor the *file-system* involved which really matters if they're *big sized* files (though it'll also depend on what is meant by *big size* as that's vague; but *big* is anything 4GB+ as those can't be written to all file-systems which is why file-system specifics matter).

Comment: Here is all the information you've asked for https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xS5c4BHzxJ/. I think the filesystem is ext4. None of them is Fat32 which has the 4GB limitation. I do transfers of more than 4GBs all the time without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is having trouble decompressing because it requires use of free space on the external drive. The more it is compressed, the more free space it needs.

I would just mount it and copy the file to the internal hard drive before decompressing it.

```
fdisk -l
```

It might be something like,

```
/dev/sdb1
```

You could then mount it.

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Search for the file path:

```
ls /mnt
```

So if it is in a subfolder,

```
ls /mnt/subfolder/
```

It lists your files by name.

Instead of:

```
unzip /mnt/subfolder/zipped.zip -d /home/user/subfolder
```

Use,

cp /mnt/subfolder/zipped.zip /home/user/subfolder

And remember to unmount the drive.

```
umount /mnt /dev/sdb1
```

And extract.

```
cd /home/user/subfolder
unzip zipped.zip
```

Comment: The file is already in my internal SSD. There's no activity in any external drive.